# How to add Cambodia state?

Tags: ce-1.9.1.0

How to add Cambodia state?
My country is Cambodia but when i select Camboida do not show "State or Province" Automate.

Example: Collection Cambodia so Many State such as: Pursat, Kompong Speu, Svay Rieng...

Answer (score 1):

Go to `System > Configuration > General > General > States Options`

In the `State is required for` multiple select field you can select Cambodia by clicking on it when holding down the CTRL key.

> **NOTE:** It is important to hold down the CTRL key when selecting Cambodia, otherwise you will deselect all other countries that were selected at the time.

[image]

You could also set `Display not required State` to `Yes` to include the State/Province in all addresses, even if not required.